# Change interface for doing a whois

Tags: routing, whois

We got 4 ips on our server, and I noticed that one of our IP's appears to be blocked by a big whois providor.

Is there a way I can route whois lookups over a different IP - not just eth0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 route add <ip of whois server>/32 <preferred interface>
```

should do it

Comment: No mention of OS, so the Windows equivalent is: `route add <ip of whois server> mask 255.255.255.255 <ip address of preferred interface>`

Comment: If there's not multiple gateways or a router handling source NATs, would specifying the alias interface be enough?

Comment: Well, the question did mention eth0, so I took a stab

Comment: Sorry, didn't answer your question. If the remote server is blocking some (but not all) of your IPs, you can use route to prefer the interface with the unblocked IP.

Comment: Thanks - it's a Debian box. route add sounds like it could be the plan! I will look into this some more.

Comment: That works great!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to alter your DNS settings to another IP address you own and alter your web server configurations to reflect the changes.

Comment: He's asking how to change the source IP when routing out of the system with a client.

Comment: Damnit, I wasn't sure if he was asking that or what. I was going to post the route answer as well, but I read into that DNS was the issue.